# Массив или база данных

Tags: c#

Возможно ли организовать такой массив ? `bitmap` | `string` | `int` | `int`

Где бы я точно знал, что:

- array[0,0] - bitmap
- array[0,1] - string
- и т.д.

Или как правильно организовать что то подобное ?

Comment: C ООП знакомы? Создайте класс с нужными свойствами и типами, а затем массив объектов этого класса. И причем здесь база данных?

Comment: @Bulson много с чем не знаком, а нужно сделать, куда копать благодаря вам понял, спасибо!